# Convergence of this Infinite Series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I was working on the series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}z^{n(n + 1)}}$ and I was to consider when $z = i$. I have that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}i^{n(n + 1)}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{\frac{3}{2}n+\frac{1}{2}n^2}}{n}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} + ... \cong 0.43882457311697565541$$

I believe it converges. Does anyone have any suggestions to find an exact value for the infinite series?

Comment: Yes, it does converge. A more precise value would be $0.4388245731174756549070447850907874370115422826636488281833961433302572905867\ldots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z) = z - \frac 12 z^2 - \frac 13 z^3 + \frac 14 z^4 + \frac 15z^5 - \frac 16 z^6 - \frac 17 z^7 + \frac 18z^8 + \cdots$

Then $(1+z^2)f'(z) = (1+z^2)(1-z-z^2+z^3+z^4-z^5-z^6+z^7+\cdots) = 1-z$

So $f'(z) = \frac {1-z}{1+z^2} = -\frac 12 \frac {2z}{1+z^2} + \frac 1 {1+z^2}$

And $f(z) = - \frac 12 \log(1+z^2) + \arctan(z)$

And finally $f(1) = - \frac 12 \log(2) + \frac \pi 4$.

You can also recognize this if you know beforehand the two corresponding infinite series

$\frac \pi 4 = \int_0^1 \frac 1{1+z^2} dz = 1 - \frac 13 + \frac 15 - \frac 17 + \cdots$

$\log 2 = \int_0^1 \frac 1{1+z} dz = 1 - \frac 12 + \frac 13 - \frac 14 + \cdots = 2(\frac 12 - \frac 14 + \frac 16 - \frac 18 + \cdots)$

Comment: If you just wrote down the last two series --whose sums are well known--that would seem to me optimal

Answer (score 1):

Your sum is 
\begin{align}
s&=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\frac1{4n+1}-\frac1{4n+2}-\frac1{4n+3}+\frac1{4n+4}\right)\\&=\frac14\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\frac1{n+1/4}-\frac1{n+1/2}-\frac1{n+3/4}+\frac1{n+1}\right)
\\&=\frac14\left(-\psi(1/4)+\psi(1/2)+\psi(3/4)-\psi(1)\right)
\end{align}
using the series representation of the digamma function $\psi=\psi_0$ (cf. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#cite_ref-AbramowitzStegun_1-1)). Now we have the well-known special values
\begin{align}
\psi_0(1/4)&=\frac12\left(-2\gamma-\pi-6\ln2\right)\\
\psi_0(1/2)&=-\gamma-2\ln2\\
\psi_0(3/4)&=\frac12\left(-2\gamma+\pi-6\ln2\right)\\
\psi_0(1)&=-\gamma
\end{align}
(given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssDigammaTheorem.html)),
so $$s=\frac{\pi}4-\frac{\ln 2}2.$$

Comment: Nice solution ! $\to +1$

Comment: Your series can be evaluated with the Taylor series of $-\log(1-z)$ (it is $\beta(1)- \frac12 \eta(1) = \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\log 2}{2}$, the $\beta$ and $\eta$ Dirichlet functions)

Answer (score 0):

The number you give is very close to $$\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{\log (2)}{2}$$ They differ by $5 \times 10^{-12}$.

I bet that you obtained this value summing up to $n=10^6$.

Now, prove it !

Comment: The value given by the OP isn't very precise. In reality, the sum and your expression differ by less than $10^{-150}$ (probably, they coincide, because there are explicit formulas for $\psi(p/q)$ with natural $p,q$ [discovered by Gauss](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssDigammaTheorem.html)).

Comment: @ProfessorVector. For sure, I totally agree ! Cheers.

Comment: It's done, now.